# Работа приложений с сетью через tor

Tags: python, linux, debian, curl, tor

Как настроить debian 8 для работы с curl, php, python через сеть tor?
т.е. при запуске например file_get_contents в php скрипте запрос должен проходить через сеть tor?

Comment: Почитайте [здесь](http://phpforum.su/index.php?showtopic=83831)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы все программы в интернет только через tor выходили, можно операционную систему внутри VM запускать — подход, иллюстрируемый [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/).

Чтобы отдельные команды TCP трафик через tor отправляли, можно proxychains утилиту использовать:

```
$ proxychains curl https://httpbin.org/ip
```

Без TCP, должен ваш публичный ip показать:

```
$ proxychains dig +short +notcp myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

а с TCP будет показывать ip через tor:

```
$ proxychains dig +short +tcp myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

Если отдельные запросы внутри программ хочется через tor направить, то можно делать запросы через SOCKS5 прокси:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:  # python2
    import urllib2

import socks  # $ pip install PySocks
from sockshandler import SocksiPyHandler  # from pysocks


opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    SocksiPyHandler(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050))
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'tor-get-ip/1.0')]
urllib2.install_opener(opener)  # install globally in the process or use *opener*


print(urllib2.urlopen('https://api.ipify.org').read().decode())
```

Запросы, которые не используют urllib2 API, идут не через tor здесь.