# Подключение к [onion] веб-сайту сети tor с помощью python

Tags: python, tor

Я хочу пропарсить определенный сайт в сети тор. Перебрал на данный момент кучу готовых вариантов, ничего пока что не заработало.

Данный вариант:

```
import requests
import json

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}

data = requests.get("http://sblib3fk2gryb46d.onion",proxies=proxies).text

print(data)
```

Выдает ошибку:

> line 832, in connect
>           super(socksocket, self).connect(proxy_addr)
>       ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Может кто сталкивался с подобной задачей и может подсказать, как реализовать?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Работа приложений с сетью через tor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/740778/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Connect to .onion websites on tor using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43682909/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предполагая, что у вас SOCKS5 прокси слушает на 9050 порту, а не каком-то другом (`sudo lsof -i :9050`), то получается обратиться к .onion сайту с вашим кодом ([через urllib также работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/740969/23044)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
    s.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
    print(s.get('https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/').headers)
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, почему у автора не получилось и чем вариант через сессии с get и прокси отличается от обычного с get и прокси?

Comment: @gil9red: код автора работает, с указанным facebook onion сервисом. Команда `lsof` из ответа, поможет автору узнать, что у него на 9050 висит или не висит

Comment: Проверил код из вопроса с `socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150` -- работает, другие адреса https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/ и http://altaddresswcxlld.onion/ -- тоже . Возможно, у автора тор на другой порт настроен? Это ведь возможно через torrc файл: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/using_tor/loop_check_url_with_many_ports.py#L16

Comment: @gil9red: порт естественно можно и другой выбрать. К примеру, [`stem` модуль позволяет свой tor процесс запустить со своим конфигом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28794647/4279) (поэтому логично нестандартные порты указывать, чтобы уменьшить вероятность конфликта)

Comment: @gil9red https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdM96.png 0. Есть код в вопросе. 1. В нём меняют протокол на `socks5`. 2. По-прежнему не работает. 3. Меняют порт на `9150` - заработало (в коде всё ещё 
 `socks5`). 4. Но не для onion (в коде всё ещё 
 `socks5`). 5. Предлагается вернуться к `socs5h` - в [ответе на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43823166/4928642) написано, почему. ВЫВОД: в коде из вопроса ошибка _только_ в номере порта.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84555/discussion-on-answer-by-jfs---onion----tor---p).